# Facebook App Share on fanpage

Tags: facebook, api

when im trying to post on my fanpages via my app, it is posting as me and not as the administrator of the page, this is my code:

```
 function getPages() {

 FB.api('/me/accounts', function (resp)
 {
 var l=resp.data.length;

     for (var i = 0, q = resp.data.length; i <q; i++)
     {
         var page = resp.data[i];

         FB.api(page.id + '/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
         if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
          } else {

          }

     });
```

This solution is working fine:

```
 FB.api('/me/accounts', function (resp)
 {
 var l=resp.data.length;

     for (var i = 0, q = resp.data.length; i <q; i++)
     {
         var page = resp.data[i];


          FB.api(page.id + '/feed', 'post', {
         message: 'GRATIS GRATIS GRATIS BIOGRAFBILLETTER TIL ALLE. Men skynd dig inden             de er væk. Tryk her for at få dem - tager kun 2 minutter:',
         status: 'success',
         url: pic 
     }, function (response) {

         if (!response || response.error) {

         } else {

         }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post to Facebook fanpage as fanpage, not user](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8034753/how-to-post-to-facebook-fanpage-as-fanpage-not-user)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using your own access token to make the post

Use the `access_token` for each page which you retrieve from the `/me/accounts` call to make the posts as the pages themselves.

Comment: Just found a dupe with a good answe: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8034753/how-to-post-to-facebook-fanpage-as-fanpage-not-user

Comment: None of them is working, is there any way that i can make you fix my script above :-)?